What is this symbol of the (Anglo-Catholic) Society of the Faith?
The Society of the Faith charity (Wikipedia entry) uses the following symbol. What is it?


This is based on the Shield of the Trinity.
The Wikipedia article at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shield_of_the_Trinity has this diagram:

